# Divergence of a series (Raabe fails)

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider $\displaystyle a_n=\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2$
>
> Prove that $\sum a_n$ diverges

Lots of factorials, so first thing is to check for ratio test (fails), Raabe test (also fails).

I can't find any lower bound that goes to infinity...

Comment: By the Stirling approximation, $a_n$ behaves like $1/n$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas do you wish to make it an answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the Stirling approximation
$$n!\sim_\infty \left(\frac ne\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$
hence

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\sim_\infty\frac{(2n)^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{2^{2n} n^{2n}\times2\pi n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$
hence we have
$$a_n\sim_\infty \frac1{\pi n}$$
and then the series is divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.